# Sliding Up <p>s

Tags: jquery, html, css, marquee

I have a simple problem which I am not able to solve properly. I have some divs having 2 `<p>`s each. The `<p>`s inside them are displayed `display:inline`. I want those both `<p>`s to slide up every 2 seconds and then make the next `<div>`'s `<p>` come up. That's somewhat hard to describe. It just like a scrolling up `<marquee>` but having a delay in between.

So here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w4XMs/).

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 1;
    $(".major_data .commitment_box .commitment").each(function () {
        $(this).attr("id", i);
        i++;
    });

    for (var j = 0; j <= $(".major_data .commitment_box .commitment").length; j++) {
        if ($(".major_data .commitment_box .commitment").prop("id") == j) {
            $(".major_data .commitment_box .commitment").animate({
                marginTop: "-=40px"
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.major_data .commitment_box {
    text-align: center;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.major_data .commitment_box .commitment p {
    display: inline-block;
}
.major_data .commitment_box .commitment p:first-child {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="major_data">
    <div class="commitment_box">
        <div class="commitment">
            <p>Alex:</p>
            <p>He's works great.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="commitment">
            <p>Alex 1:</p>
            <p>He's works great.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="commitment">
            <p>Alex 2:</p>
            <p>He's works great.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="commitment">
            <p>Alex 3:</p>
            <p>He's works great.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="commitment">
            <p>Alex 4:</p>
            <p>He's works great.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am I am clear. Thanks for any help :)

Comment: you can delay as well with transition in CSS and make mixing of effects : http://jsfiddle.net/w4XMs/7/ or http://jsfiddle.net/w4XMs/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function tick(){
        var $obj = $(".major_data .commitment_box .commitment");
        $obj.first().animate({
            'margin-top': "-=40"
        }, 1000, "linear", function() {
            setTimeout(function(){
                $obj.first().css("margin-top", "0").insertAfter($obj.last());
                tick()
            }, 1000);
        });    
    }    
    tick();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w4XMs/8/

Comment: That's great! But I want each of the 2 `<p>`s to remain in the center for a while.

Answer (score 0):

You can use delay() for it. You need a counter, to get the total wiating time for every element.
Your code is to complicated. You should use the `.each()`-Function for it.
check this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   i = 1
    $(".commitment").each(function(){
        $(this).delay(2000 * i).animate({marginTop: "-=40px"});
        i++;
    });
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w4XMs/1/